# Use C function in Swift

Tags: ios, c, swift

I want to use a C function in Swift, which has the following method definition:

```
int startTest(char *test1, char* test2)
```

If I call this method from my Swift code like this

```
startTest("test1", "test2")
```

I get the following error message:

```
'String' is not convertible to 'UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>'
```

If I change my method definition to:

```
int startTest(const char *test1, const char* test2)
```

and call that method like this:

```
var test1 = "test1"
var test2 = "test2"
startTest(&test1, &test2)
```

I get

```
'String' is not identical to 'Int8'
```

So my question is: how can I use the C function? (it is part of a library, so changing the method call could be problematic).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well you have a function accepting two chars but you're calling it with two strings.

Comment: Yes, but how can I cast a String to a char*? Thats exactly my problem, because the C function does not know String type, it can only work with char*

Comment: This question and answer might be more googlable if there was something in the title about `char *` and/or `const char *`. Perhaps consider editing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the case of

```
int startTest(const char *test1, const char* test2);
```

you can call the function from Swift simply as

```
let result = startTest(test1, test2)
```

(without the address-of operators). The Swift strings are converted automatically
to C Strings for the function call

In the case of

```
int startTest(char *test1, char* test2);
```

you need to call the function with a (variable) `Int8` buffer, because the Swift
compiler must assume that the strings might be modified from the C function.

Example:

```
var cString1 = test1.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
var cString2 = test2.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
let result = startTest(&cString1, &cString2)
```